# How to persist session/save user authentication using the TDLib Telegram library for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, authorization, tdlib

Does anyone know of a way to persist the user's session such as saving the session and loading it back into the app without the user needing to enter their phone number and go through the sign in process again?

The issue I have is that, every time I hot reload in Flutter, I need to go through that sign in process again whenever I change my code. There is a python library called Telethon which lets you save the session, but I was wondering if you could do that with the TDLib Dart library.

I've tried to read the source code to find out if there is anything I could use, but I cannot find anything.How I can persist the user's session?

**Library used:**
https://github.com/i-Naji/tdlib